# How may I estimate means and SE for an ANCOVA model fitted on multiply imputeted data with mice?

Tags: r, missing-data, ancova, lm, mice

As I have incomplete data I used `mice()` for multiply impute missing data and then I want to perform an ANCOVA. In the end what I want to get is the means and standard errors for the 2 different treatments and the confidence interval for the difference:

```
library(mice)
imp <- mice(data)
AnovaModel <- with(imp, lm(y ~ 1 + treat + cov + treat * cov))
mod_pool <- pool(AnovaModel)
predictmeans(mod_pool, "treat")
```

but I get the following error:

> Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula

So I tried in another way:

```
lsmeans(mod_pool, "treat")
```

but again:

> Error in ref.grid(object = list(call = mice::pool(object =
>   AnovaModel.PMM),  :    Can't handle an object of class  “mipo”   Use
>   help("models", package = "lsmeans") for information on supported
>   models.

So I tried with another function:

```
library(miceadds)
AnovaModel2 <- mi.anova(imp_pmm, formula = "y ~ 1 + treat + cov + treat * cov", type = 3)
lsmeans(AnovaModel2 , "treat")
```

but I get the following error:

> Error in ref.grid(object = list(r.squared = 0.544898771360605,
>   anova.table = list( :    Can't handle an object of class  “list”   Use
>   help("models", package = "lsmeans") for information on supported
>   models.

and if I try:

```
predictmeans(AnovaModel2 , "treat")
```

once again I get:

> Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula

Any suggestion?